# How do I access a third party component using ASP.NET and a JKS certificate?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, ssl, jks

I need to access a third party application that requires a JKS Certificate (which I have).

My client application is an ASP.NET one. How do I go about this?

(I would have liked to provide more information, but unfortunately I have none!)

Answer (score 1):

First, import the certificate to the windows certificate store. Have a look at http://tjworld.net/software/codesigning/JKS2PFX.html for this. If you need to use it from the aspnet account you might prefer to import it to the machines-store (instead of your accounts cert store). Use the MMC, certificates addin to check it.

Then use this certificate in your application. In most cases you will select it by its "DN=...." property (which you will also see in MMC).

HTH,
Thomas